# compare datetime and timespan value

Tags: timespan

I want to compare datetime value and timespan value for the reason of non-negative value checking ..

my code is here:

```
TimeSpan lateaftertime = new TimeSpan();
lateaftertime = Convert.ToDateTime(intime) - lateafter;
string latetime = lateaftertime.Hours + ":" + lateaftertime.Minutes;
if ((lateafter <  lateaftertime))
{
    Session["late"] = "00:00";
}
else
{
   Session["late"] = latetime;
}
```

suppose late after returns negative value means the session["late"] have the value 00:00 otherwise the session maintain the difference value

please help me. i was trouble this..

Comment: Didn't get you, it would show you the span/duration between the two ? and you are comparing Timespan vs string this won't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear, but it sounds like you *really* want:

```
if (lateaftertime < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    Session["late"] = "00:00";
}
else
{
    Session["late] = latetime;
}
```

or more concisely:

```
Session["late"] = lateaftertime < TimeSpan.Zero ? "00:00" : latetime;
```

It's possible you want `>` rather than `<` here - it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve. Sample data would make it clearer. You should also rename your variables to be more conventional, e.g. `lateAfterTime` instead of `lateafterime`

Comment: Hi i have one value in [ Datetime  DateTime lateafter = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fldlateafter"]);] and another value in timespan [lateaftertime = Convert.ToDateTime(intime) - lateafter;] How to check whether its negative or positive